# FreeBSD console resolution

Tags: freebsd, console, display

I'm trying to get higher resolution on FreeBSD 14 while booting.  I'm trying to match the same resolution I run my desktop in, 1280x720.  I'm adding this to my /boot/loader.conf:

```
efi_max_resolution="720p"
```

which gives me a nice looking boot but then also makes my xfce4 fail to start.  I am using the nvidia driver.  I have this in my rc.conf:

```
kld_list="nvidia-modeset"
```

After booting, xfce fails to start and I get the error message:

```
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs
for all framebuffer devices
```

I'm not sure what to do to fix it.  I tried some other settings I found DuckDuckGo'ng and reading https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?loader.conf(5), but nothing seems to help:

```
# vbe_max_resolution="720p"
# efi_max_resolution="1280x720"
# kern.vt.fb.default_mode="1280x720"
# kern.vt.fb.default_mode="720p"
```

Is there some more configuration I need?

Comment: Not boot related but related to X as it is xfce4 which fails. What driver are you using. See the [FreeBSD Handbook](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/x11/#x-graphic-card-drivers)

Comment: When using `nvidia` driver you need to write a X11 config. Did you do that?

Comment: I did not write an X11 config.

The handbook says "Video cards, monitors, and input devices are automatically detected and do not require any manual configuration. Do not create xorg.conf or run a Xorg -configure step unless automatic configuration fails."

xfce works, so "automatic detection" did not succeed?

Comment: The NVIDIA Drivers for both Linux and FreeBSD are binary blobs, and are not auto-discovered or configured when using a desktop environment.  Use `nvidia-xconfig` to generate an `xorg.conf` file.